# Keep html file structure after modifying it with BeautifullSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I´m using python and BeautifullSoup for finding and replacing some text on html page, and my problem is that i need to keep file struсture (indentations, spaces, new lines etc) unchanged and change only desired elements. How can I achieve this? Both `str(soup)` and `soup.prettify()` are altering source file in many ways.

P.S. sample code:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
        for element in soup.findAll(text=True):
            if not element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title','pre']:
                element.replaceWith(process(element))
    result = str(soup)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there's no easy way (or no way at all). From `BeautifulStoneSoup`'s doc:

```
__str__(self, encoding='utf-8', prettyPrint=False, indentLevel=0)
    Returns a string or Unicode representation of this tag and
    its contents. To get Unicode, pass None for encoding.

    NOTE: since Python's HTML parser consumes whitespace, this
    method is not certain to reproduce the whitespace present in
    the original string.
```

According to the note, the original whitespaces are lost to the internal representation.

Comment: maybe this is possible with other library?